# downloading torrent on a WiFi connection that requires proxy

Tags: proxy, utorrent

our college WiFi does not block torrents but any connection has to be made through a proxy server. when I use my phone as a hot spot, all my torrents download fine. when I use the proxied WiFi however, 90% of the torrents are stuck at connecting to peers though some start after I force start. is there anything I can do to make it work?

Comment: Seems like the Proxy is blocking the ports that the torrent is listening on. Try to see if you can find any opens ports while on the proxy and set your torrent up accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you need to configure your BitTorrent client (μTorrent) to use the proxy.

1. Open μTorrent's settings/preferences window from the options menu
2. Switch to the Connection pane from the menu on the left
3. Enter your Proxy details in the proxy server section
4. Check both "Use proxy for..." boxes, which will force all traffic through the proxy
5. Click OK